# VB.NET Visual Basic Power Packs not working on VS2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, toolbox, powerpacks, printform

I have downloaded the VS Basic Power Packs from the link here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx
but I have no idea why it does not appear in my project toolbox. I have also added the project reference for both the VB Power Packs and VB Power Packs Design to my project and refreshes the toolbox but it does not show at all.

Here is some pictures of it. Btw, I am using VS 2015 PRO. What did I missed out?
[image: I have added the reference to my project here.]
[image: ToolBox does not show any power packs tool.]

Comment: That second image doest tell much since none of the categories are open.   Try right click on the toolbox, then "Choose Items" then select those items you want.

Comment: @Plutonix Because usually there will be a column name of power packs. But you solved my issue! :D Please post an answer to mark.

Comment: I dont know where the category comes from but how it is treated is apparently version dependant.  On mine, the PowerPack controls are under `Common`

Comment: @Plutonix Mine did not appear automatically on any of the categories. Have to manually select them as you suggested. Thanks btw

Comment: Thanks - this worked - I couldn't believe this is the answer to just drawing something on an app. No wonder MS apps are all gray boxes even today.

Answer (score 13):

@Plutonix has the correct answer in the comments. I just thought I would add and illustrate the answer.

(NOTE: as mentioned by @Student in the question, you'll need to download the power packs because they are no longer included Visual Studio 2015. You can do so at this >> [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx) << and then continue with the rest below.)

To use the power packs, technically you don't need to add the references, all you need to do is add the power packs to the toolbox.

To do this, you right click in the toolbox and select "Choose Items"

[image]

Then the a window pops up. You can use the filter on the bottom, type "power" and then check the shape items you want to add.

[image]

Again, you should not need to add a reference, just include the power pack items, and that should do the trick. =)